# gdal_grid invdistnn with smoothing?

Tags: raster, gdal, interpolation, smoothing

I am trying to generate a raster with many pixels (10240x10240) using the `gdal_grid` tool but I have problems choosing the right interpolation algorithm.

I have a dataset with varying point density (ie some places have a lot of points, others have fewer).

- With the `invdist` algorithm, I have "false" results because points far away from a pixel can influence it too much due to their greastest density
- I tried to use the `radius1`, `radius2` and `max_points` parameters, but it seems gdal does not take the closest ones, so the result in meaningless (for my case)
- Using the `invdistnn` algorithm seems to be the solution, but there is no smoothing paramter here which I need because points have a non negligible dispertion.

(I know I could increase the data density artificially where points are missing, but then the computation time becomes very high so this is a solution I would not like to go with.)

Is there a solution to use a smoothing with the `invdistnn` algorithm ?

I am using GDAL 2.1

Comment: Invdist seems to have parameter for smoothing http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html.

Comment: Yes, invdist does, but not invdistnn, which I need since I want only the closest points to be taken into account (at least, this is my understanding :) )

Comment: It does seem to have a smooth feature documented but doesn't seem to work. Could be a bug.

Comment: smoothing with invdistnn has been implemented in GDAL 2.2. If not working, sounds like a bug indeed, but at least for my use case it works.